# Full Calendar not showing events coming from firebase reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fullcalendar

I'm using firebase with full calendar to display events from the users, currently I can see all events from the console log but on the calendar I can't see the list of events, only a blue indication that something exists there but no events is showing....

Here's my code snippet:-

```js
const DC = () => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const [createEvent, setCreateEvent] = useState("")
  const [createDate, setCreateDate] = useState("")
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
    console.log(events);

    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'calendar');

      const getEvents =  () => {
        const q = query(collectionRef);
         getDocs(q).then((eventsD)=>{
         let eventsData = eventsD.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id}))
        setEvents(eventsData)
        }).catch((err) =>{
          console.log(err)
        })
      }

      useEffect(() => {
            getEvents()
          },[])


     //Add Task Handler
   const submitTask = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await addDoc(collectionRef, {
        theEvent: createEvent,
        date: createDate,
        id: uuid(),
        timeStamp: serverTimestamp()
      })
      setButtonDisabled(true);
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  
  return (
  


{/* Modal Button */}
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#reminderModal">
Add Reminder
  </button>


       <FullCalendar
         editable={true}
         selectable={true}
        events={events}
        headerToolbar={{
          start: "today prev next",
          end: "dayGridMonth dayGridWeek dayGridDay",
        }}
        plugins={[daygridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        views={["dayGridMonth", "dayGridWeek", "dayGridDay"]}
        handleWindowResize={true}
      />

   

      {/* Modal */}
 <div className="modal fade" id="reminderModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="reminderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div className="modal-dialog">
 <form className="d-flex" onSubmit={submitTask}>
  <div className="modal-content">
    <div className="modal-header">
      <h1 className="modal-title fs-5" id="reminderModalLabel">Notify</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-body">
    
    <form>
  <input
    type="date"
    className="form-control"
    onChange={(e) => setCreateDate(e.target.value)}
  />
 
  <input
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="State client's appointment details"
    onChange={(e) => setCreateEvent(e.target.value)}
  />
 </form>
  
    </div>
    <div className="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={buttonDisabled}>Add Notifier</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 </div>
  )
  }
```

What I tried doing initially was to remove the async/await but after doing that I can't still see my events on the full calendar...

[image]

[image]

After the document shows on the calendar, the events appear nested on firebase
[image]

The code snippet that worked with which I was able to add events to firebase and view on the calendar, here's the code snippet:

```js
const DC = () => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState({
        start: "",
        end: "",
        title:"",
        date: "",
        id: uuid(),
    });
    const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
    console.log(events);

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setEvents({...events, [name]: value});
      }

    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'calendar');
      const getEvents =  () => {
        const q = query(collectionRef);
         getDocs(q).then((eventsD)=>{
         let eventsData = eventsD.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id}))
        setEvents(eventsData)
        }).catch((err) =>{
          console.log(err)
        })
      }

      useEffect(() => {
            getEvents()
          },[])

     //Add Task Handler
        const submitTask = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
            try {
            await addDoc(collectionRef, {
               ...events,
               timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
            })
            setButtonDisabled(true);
            window.location.reload();
            } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            }
        }

  return (
    <>
    <div className='dc'>

          {/* Modal Button */}
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#reminderModal">
        Add Reminder
      </button>

        <FullCalendar
         editable={true}
         selectable={true}
        events={events}
        headerToolbar={{
          start: "today prev next",
          end: "dayGridMonth dayGridWeek dayGridDay",
        }}
        plugins={[daygridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        views={["dayGridMonth", "dayGridWeek", "dayGridDay"]}
        handleWindowResize={true}
      />
      
    </div>


 {/* Modal */}
 <div className="modal fade" id="reminderModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="reminderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div className="modal-dialog">
 <form className="d-flex" onSubmit={submitTask}>
  <div className="modal-content">
    <div className="modal-header">
      <h1 className="modal-title fs-5" id="reminderModalLabel">Notify</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-body">
    
    <form>
  <input
    type="date"
    name="date"
    className="form-control"
    value={events.date}
    onChange={handleInput}
  />
 
  <input
    type="text"
    name="title"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="State client's appointment details"
    value={events.title}
    onChange={handleInput}
  />
 </form>
  
    </div>
    <div className="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={buttonDisabled}>Add Notifier</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </>
  )
}

export default DC
```

How it appears in firebase,
[image]

Comment: Not clear what you mean by a "blue indication". Can we have a screenshot? Also, please provide a sample of your event data, **in JSON format**, so we can see if there are any issues with the data content or structure which might make it incompatible with fullCalendar..

Comment: @ADyson, I've added the screenshot of the JSON format and the blue indication on the calendar above... When I add an event it shows that something is present but it's doesn't the event

Comment: That's JS object format, not JSON. But anyway it appears the event lacks some of the fields fullCalendar expects. Either store it in the correct format in firebase, or transform it as it arrives in fullcalendar. See fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing

Comment: @ADyson worked 100%... Thanks a lot. namaste

Comment: @ADyson, following up from the last solution, I observed that the events are being nested in one document when I have multiple events on the same day. It's not creating it as a single document on firebase. I've uploaded a screenshot of my console log

Comment: So you think this is an error in the creation process? And what command is that screenshot the result of, and where in your code is it?

Comment: @ADyson so let me add the new code snippet with which I was able to add events to the database that worked initially and also show how the entries reflected on firebase that would make things clearer...

Comment: @ADyson I've updated both the code snippet and how it's nesting multiple documents in one document on firebase, now I'm getting the error - "FirebaseError: too many index entries for entity"

Comment: Thanks. What does the `addDoc` function do? Is that a Firebase function? I'm not familiar with it specifically

Comment: `now I'm getting the error`...where and when?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255460/discussion-between-deezy-and-adyson).